# Windows task scheduler not calling the script when trigger is true

Tags: windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I have scheduled the in-built windows task scheduler to run python code every day, the trigger time is 11.14 AM. The thing is, I told the scheduler to run cmd and invoke the keywords `python pathtofile.py` as program arguments, but the scheduler starts the cmd from the `System32` path but does not invoke the extra arguments supplied to the scheduler. How do I make this scheduler start cmd and run the command `python pathtopythonfile.py`? I need to start the cmd and also after that happens the cmd needs to execute a python file in a remote location on my machine. I tried that with passing arguments to the scheduler when I pointed the .exe that should be called when the 11.14 M arrives and added the arguments "python file_location.py" but the arguments are not invoked when the command line starts.

The arguments were required in the interface below after I specified the program that should run.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Scheduled tasks don't have the PATH environment variable, so executable
paths need to be specified in full.

Modify your batch command to be
`\path\to\python.exe \path\to\pythonfile.py`.

Comment: What exactly were the arguments the scheduler needed me to pass, I though they were command line arguments meant to be passed to the program being called?

Comment: You need to [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1717777/edit) your post with a screenshot of the Scheduler.

Comment: Edited, waiting for post to be updated. I do believe those arguments are like command line arguments or something

Comment: Thanks for the information which I moved to your post. Running CMD like this is awkward and would require `cmd /c`, but may still not work. I suggest to put your command in a `.bat` file, and specify this file as the program to execute with no arguments. This is the standard way of doing it and it works great. If you need to set the current folder, add a `cd` command to the file.

Comment: Am really sorry but it sounds like you were using Greek for a moment there, did not understand a thing, what is a .bat file?

Comment: Trying what you said in a moment, trying

Comment: It opens up a command prompt window with the command but it does not execute, could there be a reason as to why?

Comment: @TechGeek Please don't post multiple back-to-back comments unless the maximum character limit has been exceeded; instead, please either edit the current comment, or if the 5min edit grace period has passed, copy the content into a new comment, add additional content, and delete the old

Comment: Yes, I have lost sight of what currently you are doing. Please Edit your post with the new information, including screenshots and the contents of the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide input in all 3 fields.

1. **Program/Script:** The path to your python.exe file.
2. **Add Arguments(optional):** path where the file to be executed is saved
3. **start In (Optional):** Name of your file (for e.g. test.py) to be executed.